# Auto-Layout fit to parent via code in Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, autolayout

I have a view i'm creating via code and adding to another view as subview.
The new superview can change it's frame over time and I want the newly created subview to change it's frame accordingly.
How can I do that using Auto-Layout via code in Swift?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
let view = UIView() // existing view

let subview = UIView()
subview.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

view.addSubview(subview)
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subview, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subview, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: subview, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: subview, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
```

Comment: Do I need to call updateConstraints after I do that?

Comment: It depends on where and when you are adding the constraints. If you do this in `viewDidLoad`, then there is no need to do anything.

Comment: Great! From the doc: "When developing for iOS 8.0 or later, set the constraint’s active property to true instead of calling the addConstraint: method directly. The active property automatically adds and removes the constraint from the correct view."

Answer (score 6):

**iOS 13, swift 5**

First, you add this code

```
    subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(subview)
```

Then, there are two ways of doing this in newer versions of iOS.

1. With `NSLayoutConstraint` class

   ```
   NSLayoutConstraint(item: subview, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
   NSLayoutConstraint(item: subview, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
   NSLayoutConstraint(item: subview, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
   NSLayoutConstraint(item: subview, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
   ```
2. With `NSLayoutAnchor` class (less verbose)

   ```
   subview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
   subview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
   subview.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
   subview.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
   ```

Either way, on iOS 8 and later Apple recommends using `isActive()` instead of adding constraints directly to a view.

Additionally, I believe the purpose of the `NSLayoutAnchor` method is to be more concise and readable compared to `NSLayoutConstraint`.

Answer (score 0):

As @rjobidon mentioned you should use following code (**Swift3**)

```
    let view = UIView() // existing view

    let subview = UIView()
    subview.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    view.addSubview(subview)

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: subview, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: subview, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: subview, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: subview, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also activate the constraints like that :

```
let view = UIView() // existing view

let subview = UIView()
subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

view.addSubview(subview)


NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subview.leadingAnchor),
                view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subview.trailingAnchor),
                view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subview.topAnchor),
                view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subview.bottomAnchor)
            ])
```